# How to change icon shape in Android Oreo 8.0

Tags: app-icons, 8.0-oreo

Recently updated my Google Pixel to Android Oreo 8.0. I can't find the "change icon shape" option. Where can I find it?

Comment: Why do Google think that changing the designed icon shape is acceptable? This should be an option-in option. I'm Shah frustrated not to be able to find the option to turn to default icon shape.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not mention the developer preview version. Assuming you are using dev preview 1.

The newly added menu that’s available on the **second developer preview** of Android O contains a **“Change icon shape**” option on the main **Settings** screen that’s located near the bottom of the interface, immediately above the “About” section.
Tapping that option prompts a pop-up window from which you can choose the shape.

Source: https://www.androidheadlines.com/2017/05/android-o-pixel-launcher-supports-five-app-icon-shapes.html

Comment: I'm using the final release on an HTC 10 and that option is not in my settings. The rounding makes icons ugly so if lived to find an option to turn to original.

Comment: On my Xiaomi Mi A1 this setting is in the settings of the launcher (tap and hold a free spot, then tap on Settings) and not the main settings.